# Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to **overlay** two bitmaps.
This code works fine on below android 9. On android 9 and above the application **crash**.

```
private fun overlay(base: Bitmap, blend: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        return try {
            val result: Bitmap =
                base.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
            val p = Paint()
            p.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.ADD)
            p.shader = BitmapShader(blend, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
            val c = Canvas()
            c.setBitmap(result)
            c.drawBitmap(base, 0f, 0f, null)
            c.drawRect(0f, 0f, base.width.toFloat(), base.height.toFloat(), p)
            result
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.message.toString())
            base
        }
    }
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.ex.image, PID: 26562
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps
> at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.onHwBitmapInSwMode(BaseCanvas.java:632)
> at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode(BaseCanvas.java:639)
> at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:73)
> at android.graphics.MiuiCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(MiuiCanvas.java:329)
> at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseCanvas.java:113)
> at android.graphics.MiuiCanvas.drawBitmap(MiuiCanvas.java:98)
> at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1613)
> at com.ex.image.fragments.FiltersFragment.overlay(FiltersFragment.kt:103)
> at com.ex.image.fragments.FiltersFragment.applyFilter(FiltersFragment.kt:86)
> at com.ex.image.adapters.FilterRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda-0(FilterRecyclerAdapter.kt:39)
> at com.ex.image.adapters.FilterRecyclerAdapter.$r8$lambda$KexXVg24JaLUI6vIkMTUBOYKnlY(Unknown
> Source:0)
> at com.ex.image.adapters.FilterRecyclerAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown
> Source:4)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7509)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7486)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:841)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28710)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)

**Note:**
I have already turn off the `HARDWARE_ACCELERATED` for android 9 above.

Comment: tried it does not work. I don't think its because immutability. If so this will crash on below android 9